# How to run multiple instances of the same app as producer/consumer in Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, messagebroker

i have an simple rest api that have a h2 database so my plan is when i run multiple instances of the same app they will have different in memory databases.Now i want to syncronize these databases beetwen them.I thought kafka to be a good solution , so for example when i get an POST for instance with port 8080 , i should post also for all other instances. Now my app acts as a producer/consumer at the same time and i do not know why only one instance receive the message.
The code:

```
    @EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfigForDepartment {


    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment> producerFactoryForDepartment() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, MessageEventForDepartment> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactoryForDepartment());
    }

}
```

```
    @Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment> consumerFactoryForDepartments() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "groupId");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MessageEventForDepartment.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic12")
                .partitions(10)
                .replicas(10)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForDepartments() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryForDepartments());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

```
    @Component
@Slf4j
public class DepartmentKafkaService {

    @Autowired
    private  DepartmentService departmentService;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic12" , groupId = "groupId",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForDepartments")
    public void listenGroupFoo(MessageEventForDepartment message) {
         log.info(message.toString());
    }
}
```

Why is this happening ? or maybe my approach is not very good , what are your thoughts ,guys?

Comment: May I know why you selected H2 in first place and overloading with an additional infrastructure to sync it. Why cant you consider a single db and all services connect to it? If you dont have a kafka cluster in your organisation, bring Kafka only for this purpose looks to be a bit complex for me.

Comment: This is just a requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why only one instance of the application receives each message is that each instance has the same `ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG`. Kafka's consumer protocol is such that each consumer group gets each message delivered once (obviously, there's a lot more nuance to it, but this is basically how it works).

Pawel's suggestion to use KafkaStreams is a good one—a GlobalKTable would provide what you want.

Luca Pette wrote a great primer on Kakfa Streams here: https://lucapette.me/writing/getting-started-with-kafka-streams/

Comment: But if each consumer group gets each message delivered once that does not mean that each instance will get an message because all instance are from the same group?

Comment: Not quite. The basics of Kafka are: topics are split into Partitions. Each message goes to one partition. When a consumer group has multiple instances, the partitions are divided among the instances. Therefore, only one instance will receive the message.

Comment: ok , so if i will change group id each time i start a new instance of my app and set the number of partitions lets say to 4 and my number of instances also to 4 , may this work?
P.S thanks for stream advice , i am quite new to kafka so ...

Comment: In general you just want to make sure that for every consumer group, there are more partitions than instances *of that group*, otherwise you'll have idle consumer instances which don't get assigned any partitions and therefore read no events.

Comment: However, in your use-case (which I highly recommend re-thinking as per Pawel's suggestion or the suggestion in the answer below), each group would only have one instance, so your number of partitions doesn't really matter relative to how many consumers you have.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered Kafka Streams? In my opinion, your solution is already done by internal RocksDB and Global KTable implementation in Kafka Streams.

RocksDB will behave exactly like the H2 database which you've mentioned. GlobalKTables functionality allows you to broadcast the current state to all running KafkaStreams instances and read data with ease.

Example:

1. Producer part:

```java
@RestController
class MessageEventForDepartmentController {
  
  @Autowired
  KafkaTemplate<String, MessageEventForDepartment> kafkaTemplate;

  @PostMapping(path = "/departments", consumes = "application/json")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
  void(@RequestBody MessageEventForDepartment event) {
     kafkaTemplate.send("topic-a", event.getId(), event);
  }
}
```

2. Consumer part - KafkaStreams GlobalKTable

```
@Component
public class StreamsBuilderMessageEventForDepartment {

    @Autowired
    void buildPipeline(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
        KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("MessageEventForDepartmentGlobalStateStore");
        Materialized<String, MessageEventForDepartment, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized = Materialized.<String, MessageEventForDepartment>as(storeSupplier)
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(new JsonSerde(MessageEventForDepartment.class));

        GlobalKTable<String, MessageEventForDepartment> messagesCount = messagesGroupedByUser.globalTable("topic-a", materialized);
    }
}
```

3. Read data from RocksDB

```
@RestController
class MessageEventForDepartmentReadModelController {

  @Autowired
  KafkaStreams kafkaStreams

  @Get(path = "/departments")
  MessageEventForDepartment getMessageEventForDepartment(String eventId) {
      ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, MessageEventForDepartment> store = kafkaStreams.store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType("MessageEventForDepartmentGlobalStateStore", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
   return store.get(eventId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding to your qus is that your using multiple instances for the same app which uses `IN-MEMEORY` so for `Eventually consistency` your going with Kafka stream.

MY SOLUTIONS:

1. I have used Rabbitmq mirroring which solves the same problem you have in Kafka also supports mirroring find the doc: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27846330#content/view/27846330
2. Consider redis cluster or master slave for In-memory db

Comment: MirrorMaker 1 is deprecated, and OP doesn't state having multiple Kafka clusters. Replication is already builtin feature of Kafka

Comment: So I need more to know about Kafka.